# Someone got my IP address, and I'm scared they might find me

Tags: ip

Around a year ago, I was on Reddit and clicked on a hyperlink, not knowing it grabs your IP. Ever since then, the person who grabbed my IP would sometimes comment on my Reddit posts and comments saying things like "I can't wait to meet you" and things similar to that. Should I be scared, or are they just trying to scare me for fun? (Also, their YouTube channel is called ChupplesTheClown, as the link I clicked redirected me to one of their videos.)

Comment: Just because someone has your IP doesn't mean they're going to pin down your location with any better resolution than your approximate geographic area. Not unless they have a judge who can get your ISP to give up your location, at least. Anyway, whoever is doing this is just trying to scare you. Report them for harassment if they keep up, otherwise just ignore them. I doubt you have anything to worry about.

Comment: You can "Follow" users on Reddit. That's how they know when and where you post...

Answer (score -2):

You can check what information your IP address reveals about you using free tools such as ipaddress.com

As mentioned in comments, they will not get the accurate location. They might just get the location of the cell tower your router is connected to but that's it.

Comment: Routers aren't generally connected to cell towers, but even then that's not true.

Comment: @forest They generally aren't, but if they are, you can get location of cell tower with tools from link I provided. I have tried it out myself.